# Opacity and filter causing memory leak in IE7

Tags: css, memory-leaks, filter, opacity, alpha-transparency

I have a div defined as

```
<div id="block_screen">&nbsp</div>
```

there is a stylesheet associated with its id

```
#block_screen
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9997;
    opacity: 0.25;
    filter: alpha(opacity=25);
}
```

The purpose is to show the background as translucent grey when this div is shown. That's why I am using the opacity and filter styles. It works properly. But in IE7 there is causing memory leak every time the div is shown. My guess is it is because of the opacity and filter styles which IE7 is not able to handle gracefully.
IE8 and other browsers work fine.

Are there any workarounds to this problem if I want to use IE7?

Comment: What else did you expected ? filters **should not** be used. Old IE is not capable of displaying "cool new stuff", just accept it. And when you add hacks like `Alpha(Opacity)`, because your client asked for IE6 support - you are actually ruining experience for IE6 users... With IE7 its less extreme, but same.

Comment: @c69, Where did you pick up the rule that "filters should not be used?"  Old IE (version 4, released in 1997) invented the concepts of the "cool new stuff" that is now part of the CSS3 spec.  `Alpha(Opacity)` isn't a hack, it's a solid feature that was created before CSS2 was published - well before CSS3.  And unless they are implemented to excess (like anything) they do not ruin the experience for IE6/7 users.  In this case the memory leak is most likely related to improper dom manipulation or leaked javascript events.  But it's definitely not related to the `filter` or `opacity` attributes.

Comment: @MarcusPope when not-so-bright client asked me to make galleries with alpha opacity for ie6 (in old times), poor thing was not even able to move (because you have like 20 filters) and crashed often. UI responsiveness was bad, and when you tried scrolling or resizing - the whole thing locked down for like 10 seconds, and then redrawed itself. Is this a better experience ? i dont think so. Also, DX filters were so good, that microsoft completely removes support of them from IE10.

Comment: @c69 - Hmm, I don't think that experience justifies completely avoiding the use of filters. Sounds like you had limited system resources and perhaps some reflow problems as well - both of which have workarounds. But that's why I pointed out that moderate usage doesn't ruin the experience or cause memory leaks.  And yeah, filters were deprecated in IE9 because it now supports CSS3.  That transition has nothing to do with the quality of DX hooks and everything to do with updating to modern standards.  In 1997 they were amazing, and today they're still the best polyfill for many CSS3 properties.

Answer (score 1):

In my IE specific stylesheet for ie's less than 9 I tend to use:

```
 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=85)";
filter: alpha(opacity=85);
background-color: #000;
```

Off the top of my head I believe the -ms-filter is an ie6'ism and the filter for ie7/8. I'm not getting any memory leaks so to be honest I'd be temted to look elsewhere.

Comment: You're mostly right, but the `-ms-filter` is an ie8-ism that allowed standards compliant, vendor-prefixed, filter attributes to validate against the css2.1 spec.  You can still use `filter:` in IE8 and 9, though the feature is depracated now and may not exist in IE10

Comment: also, old `filter` property now conflicts with name of [css4 filters](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html#FilterProperty).